# LINQ to Entities - Method not recognized

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I'm facing a problem with executing a query against a Queryable dataset.
The original call looks like this:

```
books = books.Where(b => (GetPropertyValue(b, filter.CategoryProperties.DbName) == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(GetPropertyValue(b, filter.CategoryProperties.DbName))) < Convert.ToInt32(filter.Value));
```

This gets me the Method not recognized error.
This of course is expected due to the call to GetPropertyValue. I then read that I should build the expression tree myself.
That result in the following code:

```
public IQueryable<Books> GetExpression(IQueryable<Books> books, BookCategoryMapping filter)
    {
        var booksExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Books), "b");
        var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("GetPropertyValue");
        var value = Expression.Call(methodInfo, booksExpression, Expression.Constant(filter.CategoryProperties.DbName));
        var left = Expression.Constant(value);
        var right = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
        var expression = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        var whereExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new Type[] { books.ElementType }, books.Expression, Expression.Lambda<Func<Books, bool>>(expression, new ParameterExpression[] { booksExpression }));
        return books.Provider.CreateQuery<Books>(whereExpression);
    }
```

Only problem being, that I get the same error. It seems like the following line only produces an expression and not the value of said expression.

```
var value = Expression.Call(methodInfo, booksExpression, Expression.Constant(filter.CategoryProperties.DbName));
```

Any help producing the correct expression tree would be greatly appreciated :-)

EDIT:
Here's the GetPropertyValue method:

```
public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            return obj.GetType().GetProperty(name)?.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.Log(LogLevel.Error, null, ex);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: You answered your question yourself: you cannot use a C# method in a Linq-to-entities query, since the calling of the method cannot be converted to SQL. It doesn't change anything if you let the compiler build your expression, or if you build the expression yourself - it still cannot be converted to SQL.

Comment: I think that the solution `build the expression tree myself` is meant as in: convert the contents of the method `GetPropertyValue` into an expression, so it **can** be translated to SQL. At the moment you are converted the **calling of the method** into an expression tree, but you have to convert **the entire method** into an expression tree.

Comment: Can you add the method `GetPropertyValue` to the question?

Comment: @Maarten Edited with the code :-)

Comment: Your method `GetPropertyValue` uses reflection to look up a property value. That is hard to translate to SQL.

Comment: @Maarten So I've realized :D

Comment: You can replace your call to `GetPropertyValue` with `Expression.Property(...)`.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie That will give me the Property, but not that value of the property, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Expression.Property(...) creates a property value access, so it does represent the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method below generates an `Expression<Func<Book, bool>>` which determines whether a given property of a `Book` is less than a given (constant) value. The error-checking code you currently have in `GetPropertyValue` can probably be replaced by catching the `ArgumentException` which will be thrown when you try to create an expression for a nonexistent property.

Note that I have assumed that the property you're accessing is genuinely numeric, and that your call to `Convert.ToInt32` was only necessary because your `GetPropertyValue` method returns an `object`.

```
Expression<Func<Book, bool>> GenerateLessThanExpression(string propertyName, int value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (Book));
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var comparison = Expression.LessThan(property, Expression.Constant(value));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Book, bool>>(comparison, parameter);
}
```

Here's a sample usage to return only very short books:

```
var filter = GenerateLessThanExpression("Pages", 5);
var filtered = books.Where(filter);
```

Comment: One comment I will add to this. In the Expression.LessThan I had to parse a type as the third parameter, otherwise I could not get it to work :-)

Comment: Can you clarify this? The code above was tested with sample classes and works as-is. What type did you "parse"?

Comment: I parsed, property.Type and of course made sure that the value I compared it to was of the same type